# using mod_rewrite with $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, forms, get

I'm trying to make seo to search queries. i've got a form like this:

```
 <form action="index.php?<?=$_GET['search-input01']?>'" method="get">
   <p class="nom t-center">
     <label for="search-input01">All:</label>
     <input type="text" size="75" name="q" id="search-input01" />
     <input type="image" src="design/search-button.gif" class="search-submit" />
   </p>
 </form>
```

when u do search  `/index.php?q=SEARCHTERMHERE&x=0&y=0` in adress bar. I want to make this: `/search-SEARCHTERMHERE`

how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/search-'.rawurlencode($_GET['q']));
    exit;
}
```

This will redirect a request that’s URL query contains a `q` argument like in your `/index.php?q=SEARCHTERMHERE&x=0&y=0` to `/search-SEARCHTERMHERE`.

---

**Edit**    You can also try this with mod_rewrite only:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /index\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&+)*)q=([^&]*)&*(.*)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /search-%3?%1%4 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^search-(.+) index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first rule is to redirect the request externally and the second is for the internal rewrite.

Comment: thank you for your answer. your code redirecting succesfully but dont work. mozilla says wrong redirection (never loading page on ie) btw i changed my post. forget about "www" it was search term. i want /index.php?q=SEARCHTERMHERE&x=0&y=0 to /search-SEARCHTERMHERE

Comment: it wasnt worked but i changed "q" to "search-input01" in php script $_get. it works but writing like search-TERM?x=0&y=0. and pages are not working now. RewriteRule search-(.*)-(.*)$  /index.php?page=$2&q=$1
RewriteRule search-(.*)-(.*)$  /index.php?type=$2&q=$1
RewriteRule search-(.*)-(.*)-(.*)$  /index.php?page=$3&type=$2&q=$1 there are other rules. if u have MSN add me alee@depyronick.com

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the opposite of what Gumbo suggested, i.e. redirect `/search-SEARCHTERM` to `/index.php?q=SEARCHTERM&x=0&y=0`, enter something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search-([-_A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?q=$1&x=0&y=0 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for update. i tried 
RewriteRule ^search-([-_A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /index.php?q=$1&x=0&y=0 [L]

but this is not worked

Comment: can you give an example of a typical search term?

Comment: um. ex search term: "windows" when u do search "windows" in "all" section page goes to "index.php?q=windows" in "applications" section goes to "index.php?type=app&q=windows"

Comment: IF the index.php is not in your server root, remove the / before index.php. Have you tried adding <?php var_dump($_GET); ?> to your index.php to see what paramters are passed?